# SVG symbols do not fire onload event (only in firefox). I look for a workaround

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, svg

I am working with D3.js in a project to make a diagram with SVG. The diagram uses SVG symbols. And I have javascript code to manage these items with onload events.

In browsers such as webkit engine browsers runs very fine. But Firefox...Firefox does not run any onload event into a SVG.

Well, I saw the bug and thought Firefox is free software and these people loves the bugtracking. And I have uploaded the bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1254159.

And the response from these people is a "WONTFIX".

The example for to check the bug is tiny and clear:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test onload event in a svg symbol</title>
        <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" pointer-events="all" width="500px" height="500px" style="background: #ffff00;">
            <g class="cat" transform="translate(100 100)">
                <use xlink:href="animals.svg#cat" onload="javascript: console.log('This message is not showed in firefox.');" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.select("svg")
                .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "dog")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(200 200) scale(0.5)")
                    .append("use")
                        .attr("xlink:href", "animals.svg#dog")
                        .on("load", function() {
                            console.log("And this message is not showed in firefox too.");
                        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I look for in the w3c documents and the event onload in symbols are standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement

Has anybody a workaround for this?

Comment: Put your code in the SVGLoad event of the outer `<svg>` element.

Comment: But the SVG is loaded, and the javascript adds anothers symbols on the fly such as add a image into a web by javascript. As you can see in the second example in the code.

Comment: Have the animals.svg file call some function in the parent html file on its load event then.

Answer (score 0):

A long way around this is to deal with the loading of the external resources yourself (or rather, with the help of d3).

D3 has an xml loader function (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_xml), and svg is xml, so you can do the following:

- prepare the content which does not use external resources
- use d3 to load the svg
- in the callback function of d3.xml, you get a DOML element: insert it at the relevant place in the graphic, and do any work you would be doing in the "onload" event.

*(There might be a simpler way, I just don"t know about it)*